# How can I append values from an Ajax response to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

Before my Ajax function is called, I have a global scoped `names` array like this:

```
var names =  ["John Smith","Mike Jones","Jenny White","April Brown"];
```

In the `success` function of the ajax call I need to erase the array and repopulate it with new names passed back to the page in Json format (`v.name` in the example below).

But I'm not sure how to append to the array in the course of my `$.each` loop:

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {

      // how to add `v.name` to the `names` array?

  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have already cleared `names`, try this:

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
      names.push(v.name);
  });
});
```